# Backup and Restore while changing harddisk

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, restore, system-restore

Lenovo is going to replace my Harddisk under warranty because the diagnostic tests show some error (though I am still not facing any issues).

However, there are only going to replace the disk and give me a blank disk. What's the best option for setting up everything back again on the new hard disk. Is there any software I can use for doing the quickest restore.

My Laptop came originally with either 8.0 - which was then upgraded to 8.1 & then Windows 10. It did not come with any recovery disk. The vendor says that the license is in the ROM - it will be automatically taken care of when I reinstall Windows - but I don't want to reinstall/upgrade etc - will take me 2 days.

What can be done to ease the whole process? Willing to pay for software.

Comment: Do you have a USB backup drive of the same size or bigger? If you do, you can use disk imaging software and put the disk image on it, then restore it after you get your new hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I'd clone the hard disk using Clonezilla.  You may need a USB to SATA adaptor or caddy.  You'll also need a CDROM drive to boot Clonezilla (although there may be a USB stick version, I don't know)